# Troubles with Qt 5.6 QSsqlSocket in android 6

Tags: android, qt, qsslsocket

i have some troubles with the class QSslSocket in my app in android 6, I develop in Qt 5.6 and in the versions  below of android 6 the app runs normally.

The problems are the following:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_free   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CipherFinal   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_rc2_cbc  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf  
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EC_get_builtin_curves   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf     
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves   
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EC_get_builtin_curves
```

Any idea how to solve this problems?

Answer (score 1):

You need to start packaging and providing OpenSSL yourself. It is not an option for Android 7, you absolutely must do it.